# Best practice with caching. Avoid redundant caching?

Tags: javascript

Ok this question might seem a bit basic but I wonder if I should cache variables in functions like these:

```
function fooBar(target) {
  var elem = target.children[0].children[1];

  if(n == 1) {
    elem.style.color = "red";
  }
  else {
    elem.style.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

vs

```
function fooBar(target) {   
  if(n == 1) {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "red";
  }
  else {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

There is no real performance gain is there? I assume apart from type safety the latter is better since I need less lines. What exactly is considered best practice in cases like these? Should I still cache the object eventhough its not needed?

So unless my if statements included:

```
if(elem.className == "something")
```

I personaly wouldnt bother caching.

At the other hand my brain is in conflict with coding style / consistency.

Assuming I have something like this:

```
function fooBar(target) {   
  if(n == 1) {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "red";
  }
  if else (n == 2) {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "blue";
  }
  if else (n == 3) {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "yellow";
  }
  else {
    target.children[0].children[1].style.color = "green";
  }
}
```

Then I would have to cache the object due to typesafety which brings me back to the issue of consistency...

Comment: less lines doesn't necessarily means less bytes (and comparison must be done with double or triple equality)

Comment: When you use element more then once - __always__ cache it in a variable. Especially true when you use DOM elements.

Comment: @u_mulder updated my question

Comment: @fcalderan updated question

Comment: *Performance* is basically a nonissue for such trivial operations, so don't call it "caching". It mostly comes down to code readability and maintainability, and for that you need to draw your own conclusions based on the specific situation.

Comment: If your methods are small, concise and have no side effects than type-safety shouldn't be an issue. Readability/maintainability, performance (query DOM) and memory should all be what is considered. Whilst something as trivial as you posted the only real benefit would be readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is considered best practice in cases like these?

The "best practice" in "such" cases is to eliminate read(access) operations upon array/object.
In your case you have 4 read operations for both two variants. 
**-** To avoid multiple read/access operations you should save the crucial element(reference) into a local variable
**-** To avoid multiple `if else` statements - use `switch` operator instead(it should go faster)
You should also consider the **code readability** and **code simplicity**.
 But if you need *"the less lines"* - I would suggest the following simple and scalable solution for your last example:

```
function fooBar(target) {
  var styles = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];  // of course, if "n" increases consecutively (can be also transformed into object)  
  target.children[0].children[1].style.color = styles[n] || styles[0];
}
```

Comment: This is not a best practice at all in my opinion

Comment: @IvanYarych, as you said, "it's your opinion". Do you know the best practices? When I say "best practices" - I rely on N.Zacas, D.Crockford, D.Flanagan works ... What do you rely on ?

Comment: I think all answers in this topic are correct and there is no point of arguing really.  I would go further with your code example and use JavaScript's magic `||` operator: `target.children[0].children[1].style.color = styles[n] || styles[0];`

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk, of course, exactly ... just forgot for the moment. `||` would the final concise thing. Thanks

Comment: Wow this is some great input.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on practices in your workplace. Or if it is for your private projects, on what you like.
I personally don't like repeating myself, especially with a long lines of code, and so I would go with the first approach.
The first approach also gives you a benefit of changing just one line of code, if at some point in the future you need to change different variable. In the second approach a bad developer might change one line and leave the other (albeit provided a good suit of tests this should not matter as you would expect tests to fail).
I would say: If you are accessing the same deeply nested variable in multiple places, make your life easier and protect yourself against silly errors by assigning that deeply nested variable to a local variable with a good descriptive name. At the end of the day `elementColor` is better than `target.children[0].children[1].style.color`.

Comment: Daniel you are right. I would you do the same for strings. For example assuming we a string "Active" which i set as a  className in 2 conditions. Would you cache it too?

Comment: This is a different situation, and is called "Magic string" and should always be avoided. By looking at code, you have to ask yourself a question: "What 'active' means? Can I figure out the meaning based on value?". I always assign values like that to a descriptive variable, so if someone coming to the code after me sees it, they straight away know what is going on. This also gives you benefit of changing once instead of changing it in 10 different places...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not performance, but readability. It is often a good practice to perform assignments that let you or someone else read code easier and avoid making a mistake in future.

I personally would use a shortcut even if that variable is used only once, like this:

```
function fooBar(target) {
    var element = target.children[0].children[1];

    element.style.color = "red";
}
```

It may also help to give the variable meaningful name if you know what will be stored there. For example: `bodyElement`, `dropdownElement` or shortcuts like `bodyEl`, `dropdownEl` and so on.

Comment: I tend to agree, long paths on the left side of an assignment are a pain :)